# Простой пример создания мира на Box2D

Tags: box2d

Привет, выбирал физический движок недавно. Получилось, что лучше, чем box2d, не нашел.

С этим движком я долго борюсь. И пока ничего не выходит... Даже по мануалам консольный мир не смог создать. Какое-то у авторов расхождение теории с практикой. Может кто поделиться проектом, где просто создается к примеру мир, или вообще что-то создается? 
Хочется написать простую игруху, например как тут: [Splasher Game](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splasher-game/id953136041?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8)

Спасибо)

---

Большое спасибо за код! Но он не работает....

```
#include<Box2D\Box2D.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){

const b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);

    b2World world(gravity);
}
```

Вылетает:

```
 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::b2World(struct b2Vec2 const &)" (??0b2World@@QAE@ABUb2Vec2@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Конечно я понимаю, что перед вопросом надо погуглить.... Я гуглил уже такие ошибки, но ничего полезного не узнал.... Ссылка на релиз не работает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пара хороших ссылок:

- [Box2D в картинках](http://flashnotes.ru/2010/02/24/box2d-v-kartinkax-–-chast-2-privet-mir/) ;
- [Урок::: Box2DFlash 2.1a](http://redefy.net/2011/09/26/box2dflash-chapter-2/);
- [Box2D v2.0.2 Руководство](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1taHWCfoCFFwdn0itFXSS5lKoHKebx4Z-27yZJ6vVACc).

А ты на каком языке пишешь? Я на c# использовал движок. Привожу куски своего кода. :)

Создайте мир

```
world_ = new World(border_, gravity_, true);// world
```

Создайте объект какой-нибудь

```
_polygon = new Rectangle();
myBrush = Brushes.Red;
/// пол
_polygon = new Rectangle();
_polygon.Fill = myBrush;
_polygon.Width = width;
_polygon.Height = 10;
Canvas.SetLeft(_polygon, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(_polygon, heigth - 10);
canvas1.Children.Add(_polygon);
Body polBody_;
BodyDef polDef = new BodyDef();
polDef.Position.Set((float)width / 2, (float)(heigth - 10) + 5);
polDef.UserData = _polygon;
PolygonDef shapepolDef = new PolygonDef();
shapepolDef.SetAsBox((float)((_polygon.Width) / 2), (float)((_polygon.Height) / 2));
shapepolDef.Density = (float)0.0; //  плотность
shapepolDef.Friction = (float)1.0; // коэффициент трения
shapepolDef.Restitution = (float)0.1;//упругость
polBody_ = world_.CreateBody(polDef);
polBody_.CreateShape(shapepolDef);
polBody_.SetMassFromShapes();
```

Затем создайте таймер

```
public void time()
{
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a)
    {
        updateWorld();
    });
}
```

И в методе отрисовывайте каждую фигуру

```
private void updateWorld()
{
    for (Body list_ = world_.GetBodyList(); list_ != null; list_ = list_.GetNext()) {
        if (list_.IsStatic()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (list_.GetUserData() == listRectangle[countR]) {
            vec = list_.GetPosition();
            float angle = (float) (list_.GetAngle() * (180 / System.Math.PI));
            RotateTransform rot = new RotateTransform();
            angle = angle - (float) System.Math.Truncate(angle / 360) * 360;
            rot.Angle = angle;
            rot.CenterX = 0;
            rot.CenterY = 0;
            listRectangle[countR].RenderTransform = rot;
            double Xn = 0, Yn = 0;
            Xn = (-dlinaRectangle[countR]) * System.Math.Cos(list_.GetAngle()) - (-chirinaRectangle[countR]) * System.Math.Sin(list_.GetAngle()) + vec.X;
            Yn = (-dlinaRectangle[countR]) * System.Math.Sin(list_.GetAngle()) + (-chirinaRectangle[countR]) * System.Math.Cos(-list_.GetAngle()) + vec.Y;
            Canvas.SetLeft(listRectangle[countR], Xn);
            Canvas.SetTop(listRectangle[countR], Yn);
            countR--;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Я на C/C++... Уроков я уже насмотрелся столько..... Эти видел тоже...
Очень нужен проект бы на с++ и мануал к версии 2.2.1

Comment: @sergileon, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Ну вот, уже подчеркивает... gravity нужно было создавать же? Первой строкой уже студия не довольна..(
world_ = new World(border, gravity, true);// world
я нижние подчеркивания убрал если что...  Этот код точно должен работать? Подключил библиотеку бокса, в майн записал первую строку вашего кода и ... error C2065: 'world' : undeclared identifier
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'World' Что не так уже????????

Comment: @Alerr Я бы на вашем месте начал с [**`C++ Primer`**](http://www.amazon.com/Primer-3rd-Edition-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201824701), а не с `Box2D`.

Comment: @Alerr Хочу сказать, что фразы типа *"первой строкой уже студия недовольна"* и неумение разобраться с наличием / отсутствием нужных хедеров и с тем, как использовать сущности из хэдеров (пусть даже и с "неправильной справочной информацией") намекают на то, что `C++ Primer` вы читали плохо.

Comment: Конечно это глупый вопрос. А что делать если уже ни в чем не уверен? Читать их мануал, который не работает? Подозреваю что студия глючит или вообще не знаю что.... И пример дали...спасибо конечно,... но написали бы пару строчек, но работающих!

Comment: @Alerr

- Вам привели код на `C#` как пример, естественно, что в `C++` он не будет компилироваться.

- Набросал для вас совершенно тривиальный [**пример.**](https://gist.github.com/3744788)

- В релизе [`Box2D_v2.2.1.zip`](http://box2d.googlecode.com/files/) есть папка `Documentation\API,` в которой можно найти актуальную `Doxygen` документацию для текущей версии `Box2D.`